# Help with big O notation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I've been having some problems trying to grasp the concept of big O notation. So, by definition big O is as follows, `T(n) ∈ O(G(n)) if T(n) <= G(n) * C`.

Since the the constant "C" can be any integer > 0, wouldn't this following example be true as well?

Example:

```
n log n ∈ O(log n)
n log n <= log n * c
```

Where C is equal to the value of n.

I know that the answer is that `n log n ∉ O(log n)` but I don't understand how since C can be any constant.

Thanks in advance for your help :D

Comment: @Jacob, obviously. Doesn't make it a bad question though. bigO is something every programmer should understand.

Comment: Not homework, just clarifying somethings before a midterm exam

Comment: @Steven, I wish they had the intarwebs (specifically SO) when I was in college. Would have saved me many many hours in the dungeon (CS library in basement of sciences building). Good luck on your exam!

Comment: Thanks Byron, and thanks again everyone for giving such great answers :D

Answer (score 11):

c is just that, a *constant*.  This means that you can't say "let c be the value of n", because you must choose some c first and then allow the comparison to hold for all n.

In other words, in order for some T(n) to be O(G(n)), there must exist *no* constant c such that G(n)*c is greater than T(n) for all n.

Thus n log n is not O(log n) because, no matter what constant you choose, n > c will cause n log n to be greater than c log n.

Answer (score 4):

Let me repeat your words.

> c can be any **constant**.

This means that c can not depend on n.

Answer (score 4):

the idea is that the inequality holds for any n and a *fixed* c. so while you might find a certain c such that n log n < c log n, (namely any c>n), you can easily find other n' for which it doesn't hold (namely n'>c).

Comment: I think the source of this misunderstanding is that you choose c at *some* point. But that's once per function class, not once per n.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if n=C then C is not a constant. And in most real-world algorithms, C is small so the big-O part usually dominates for typical values of n.

But big-O complexity is concerned with the efficiency of an algorithm for large n, especially as n approaches infinity. In other words it tells you the scalability of an algorithm: how well a given algorithm handles a very large or doubled workload.

If you know that n is *always* small then the big-O complexity is not that important, rather you should focus on the wall-clock time required by the algorithm. Also, if you are choosing between two algorithms that have the same big-O complexity (e.g. O(n log n)), quite often one is better than the other (e.g. random-pivot quicksort generally outperforms a binary heap sort).

Comment: "in most real-world algorithms, c is small so the big-O part usually dominates for typical values of n": this is confusing one c - the constant used for determining that a certain algorithm is O(something) - with a completely different c, the constant factor in a program's run-time (ie runtime=3X+c).  These are not the same.

Comment: The OP used "C" as the multiplicative factor, not the constant added term. I was just using the same language (sorry about the lowercase "c").

Comment: That's not what I meant.  And, actually, in the original question a lower-case 'c' was used.  Read the sentence I selected very carefully and you will see that it cannot be referring to the arbitrary multiplicative constant from the OP's post - because the OP's 'c' is a chosen counterexample, not a factor of a "real-world algorithm".  "c is small in most real-world algorithms" is referring to a run-time coefficient.

Comment: @Borealid: Nope, I still have no idea why you are talking about an additive "+c".

Comment: If an algorithm on n elements performs n+k operations, it is O(n).  The way you prove it is O(n) is by saying "there exists no X such that X*n > j*(n+k) for all n".  The variable you *must* refer to when you say "in most real-world algorithms, C is small" is the constant factor of real-world run time (`k` above).  It cannot be the existential variable (`X` above) nor the existential constant (`j`) because these do not exist for "real-world algorithms".  But you say "if n=C then C is not a constant".  Therefore, somewhere in your first two sentences you are confused.

Answer (score 1):

In the definition you should determine C just by the T and G themselves. This is what a constant C means. So C should not depend on the input of them. So you can not consider C = n

Answer (score 1):

in the expression n log n, you can't compare the outside n to C, like you are doing.  That would be like taking the algrebraic expression x(x+1) and replacing one of the x's with a constant.

In n log n, n is a variable.  In the big O expresion, C is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The value of n depends on the input set, the value of C is fixed.

So yes, if n = 16 and C = 256, it looks like n^2 * lg(n) for a small input set.  Now increase the input set to 100,000,000; the value of C stays at 256, you now have 256 * lg (100,000,000)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I'm stuck on big-oh, I find it useful to think of it as a competition:
I choose a big-oh function (so, in your case, logn) and a constant (c). The important thing is that I have to choose a real value. I usually pick a thousand, just because.
Then I have to let my arch-nemesis pick *any n he chooses*. He typically chooses a billion.

Then I make the comparison.

To finish the example, 10^9*(log(10^9)) is now made clearly much bigger than 1000log(10^9). Thus, I know that the big-oh won't work.